# Getting user_likes in Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the current user's likes after they have signed into my iOS app using Facebook. The only things I can get from the user are their profile (gender, locale, etc).

How would I go about requesting permission to get their user_likes, after they have logged in?

Also, would I have to get my app reviewed by the Facebook team? I've read somewhere that I may have to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide login permission for user_likes and if others then as follows:

self.LoginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_likes",@"email",@"user_relationships",@"user_interests",@"user_hometown",@"user_about_me",@"user_games_activity",@"user_relationship_details",@"user_religion_politics"];

self.LoginView.delegate=self;

There after you need to call webService using graph Api by simply calling the method ( **[self obtainUserData]**) which is mentioned as follows:

-(void)obtainUserData

{

NSString *fbAccessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;

```
NSString *fields =@"id,name,first_name,last_name,picture,permissions,installed,music,likes,email,friends,gender,birthday,email,hometown,relationship_status,interested_in,sports";

// feed is use for all action
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=%@",fields];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&access_token=%@", path,fbAccessToken]];
NSLog(@"%@",url);

NSURLRequest *req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
// NSMutableData *jsondata=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
self.receivedData = data;
[conn start];
```

}

//here receivedData is an object of NSMutable Data

you will obtain your required output in following method:

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

NSMutableDictionary *json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_receivedData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

```
    NSLog(@"json: %@",json);
```

}

HopE this Helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but i get null for the result JSON.